# PHPUnit testing the add action - Test failure

Tags: phpunit, cakephp-3.0

CakePHP Version: 3.5.17
PHPUnit: 6.5.8

**Example code:**

**Users controller add action. (Code which errors.)**

```
public function add()
{
    $user = $this->Users->newEntity();
    if ($this->request->is('post')) {

        // Initialise the client id.  
        if ($this->clientId() === false) {
            //$errorLocation = 'Users Controller - Line ' .  __LINE__;
            //if ($this->recordError($errorLocation) === false) {
                //throw new UnauthorizedException();
            //}
            //throw new UnauthorizedException();  
        }
        else {
           $clientID = $this->clientId(); 
        } 

        $user = $this->Users->patchEntity($user, $this->request->getData());

        // Declare the client id for save.
        $user->cid_1 = $clientID;

        if ($this->Users->save($user)) {
            $this->Flash->success(__('The user has been saved.'));
            return $this->redirect(['action' => 'index']);
        }
        $this->Flash->error(__('The user could not be saved. Please, try again.'));
    }
}
```

**Client id function.**

```
public function clientId()
{
    $session = $this->request->session();
    if ($session->check('Cid.one')) {
        $clientID = $session->read('Cid.one');
        if (!is_string($clientID) || is_numeric($clientID) || (strlen($clientID) !== 40)) {
            return false;
        }
        return $clientID;
    }
    return false;
}
```

**The process.**

When a user logs in I select the $clientID and store it in a session and use it in many of my select statements within the application.

**The error**.

Undefined variable clientID - EG: The client id is not being retrieved from the function which errors on save.

**Summary.**

This makes sense to me because I can run a unit test without being logged in and the client id is retrieved on login. EG: How can the client id be there when testing!

**My Solution.**

Instead of using a session I use a finder as shown below.

**Users controller add action. (Code which passes.)**

```
public function add()
{
    $user = $this->Users->newEntity();
    if ($this->request->is('post')) {

        // Declare the id from auth component.
        $id = $this->Auth->user('id');

        // Select the client id. 
        $query = $this->Users->find('cid', [
            'id' => $id
        ]);

        if ($query->isEmpty()) {
            $errorLocation = 'Users Controller - Line ' .  __LINE__;
            if ($this->recordError($errorLocation) === false) {
                throw new NotFoundException();
            }
            throw new NotFoundException();
        }

        // Initialise the variables and retrieve the data.
        $clientID = '';
        foreach ($query as $row):                           
           $clientID = $row->cid_1;
        endforeach;

        $user = $this->Users->patchEntity($user, $this->request->getData());

        // Declare the client id for save.
        $user->cid_1 = $clientID;

        if ($this->Users->save($user)) {
            $this->Flash->success(__('The user has been saved.'));
            return $this->redirect(['action' => 'index']);
        }
        $this->Flash->error(__('The user could not be saved. Please, try again.'));
    }
}
```

**My question:**

Is there a way to simulate the $clientID from the session for the test?

I was wondering if there was something similar to using: $this->session(['Auth.User.id' => 1400]); in my test which simulates an 
authenticated user but for other session data such as the client id?

**Why I ask.**

It's performance related. As far as I know it's quicker to declare a value from a session than to select a value from a database.

Thanks Z.

Comment: There can be no "undefined variable" error in the shown code, the logic either throws an exception, or defines the variable. Please make sure that you've posted the correct code.

Comment: @ndm - Sorry about that, I commented out the exception to reveal the undefined variable error when I was debugging and forgot to comment in out when I posted. I've edited my post now so it should read correctly.

Comment: Have you tried using `$this->session(['Cid.one' => XXX]);`? Seems that you know to use `$this->session` to write Auth data; it should work to write anything else you might want into the session as well.

Comment: @Greg Schmidt - I did try that but I still couldn't get the test to pass but I've just tried it again and it works so I'm not sure what I did wrong last time. Also even if it had of worked I still would not have been confident that I was using the framework correctly so to have that confirmed is a big help. If you post that as an answer I will tick as correct and many thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The manual section on [Testing Actions That Require Authentication](https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/development/testing.html#testing-actions-that-require-authentication) shows how to set variables in the session. But it's not limited to just the Auth section; in your test code, you can set any required session variables you need. In your case:

```
$this->session(['Cid.one' => XXX]);
```